# Powershell WebSocket(ClientWebSocket) send message

Tags: powershell

Env: MacOs

I am trying to create a menu using `System.Net.HttpListener`.

Is there any way to use `[System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket]$WebSocket` to send information to the browser client using Powershell?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this, but in order for the web server to send any info to the browser, the browser has to initiate the request, most commonly this would happen with JavaScript.

First off, to setup the HTTP listener for the server.

```
#Setting up the listener
$Server = [System.Net.HttpListener]::new()
$Server.Prefixes.Add('http://localhost:8001/')
$Server.Start()
```

This starts the webserver listening for requests on the specified entry point.  Next up, we define a short helper function which this script will use to encapsulate sending responses back to the browser.

```
Function Send-WebServerResponse($InputObject){
    $JSON = $InputObject | ConvertTo-Json
    $buffer = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($JSON)
    $Context.Response.ContentLength64 = $buffer.Length
    $Context.Response.OutputStream.Write($buffer, 0, $buffer.length)
    $Context.Response.OutputStream.Close()
    }
```

The next step is to write what would be the Controller logic if this were an MVC app.  Basically the Routing layer so the script knows how to respond depending on the type of request..

```
#Listening for a particular header value
$Context = $Server.GetContext()

    Write-Host "$($Context.Request.UserHostAddress) [$($Context.Request.HttpMethod)]=> $($Context.Request.Url)"  -ForegroundColor Green    

$RequestData = $Context.Request.Headers.GetValues('RequestData')
    if ($Context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath -eq '/TestMe'){
        Write-Host "Received request for /TestMe endpoint..."  -ForegroundColor Green
        $Body = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($Context.Request.InputStream, $Context.Request.ContentEncoding)
        $Data = $Body.ReadToEnd() | convertfrom-stringdata
        $Body.Close()
        Send-WebServerResponse "Request Received successfully to /TestMe"

    }
```

Finally, here is what the JS would look like to request the info from this listener:

```
$.ajax({
            //the url to send the data to
            url: "TestMe",
            //the data to send to
            data: {SomeParam : "SomeValue"},
            //type. for eg: GET, POST
            type: "POST",
            //datatype expected to get in reply form server
            dataType: "json",
            //on success
            success: function(data){
                if (data){
                    Console.Log("Request Success");
                }
                else{
                    Console.Log("Request Failed!");
                }


            },
            //on error
            error: function(){
                //bad request

            }
        });
```

Wrote this answer with help to @ScottCorio who taught me this method.

Comment: Thanks looks promising, how do I reply the "$.ajax"

Comment: We did a session together on this topic at MMS2019, MMSJazz2019 and maybe even one at MMS2020 if it happens this year